# Different command for each button in object tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have to generate buttons (the number depends on the characters in the word), and so that each button, when pressed, performs its own separate function.
Part code:

```
q = ['w', 'o', 'r', 'd']
s = (1, len(q))
a = np.zeros((s))
for i in range(0, a.shape[0]):
    for j in range(0, a.shape[1]):
        b = tk.Button(symbolsFrame, text= q[j], font = "Arial 12", bg = "white")#, command = lambda: btn_func())
        b.grid(row=i, column=j, padx = 3)
        v.append(b)
```

How can I assign each button, for example, so that when I click, the pressed letter is displayed in the console?
When iterating over a list with a button, I get this result, but I don’t know what to do with it:

```
.!frame.!training.!frame.!button
.!frame.!training.!frame.!button2
.!frame.!training.!frame.!button3
.!frame.!training.!frame.!button4
```

if i change "command":

```
b = tk.Button(symbolsFrame, text= q[j], font = "Arial 12", bg = "white", command = lambda: print(q[j]))
```

When I click any button, send only last symbol:

```
.!frame.!training.!frame.!button
.!frame.!training.!frame.!button2
.!frame.!training.!frame.!button3
.!frame.!training.!frame.!button4
d
d
d
d
```

Comment: In your button command, try:
`lambda j=j: print(q[j])`

Comment: Wow, its work, thank you very very much. But can you explain what is j = j ?

Comment: When you were calling the command, it looked for the current value of j, which was used in the for loop. So the most recent value of j was j's last value after the for loop ended. j=j forces the computer to store the current value of j as the for loop is in progress, so it isn't looking up j's value at the end of the for loop.